# what really @layout/bg_player_header indicates?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, layout

I have seen this line of code in many source code xml files -

```
android:background=" @layout/bg_player_header".
```

Also this-

```
android:background="@layout/bg_player_footer"
```

But I haven't been able to understand what does it really signifies . 
Why they used `@layout` instead of `@color`? What changes by doing that ?

Comment: is this not in your layout folder? Should be there. Maybe post the code inside bg_player_header file.

Comment: It is, but it shows as red or error. I dont know what to do about that .

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol  @layout/bg_player_header

Comment: that means that file isn't inside your layout folder

Comment: But the xml file is inside the layout folder

Comment: Do I need to create bg_player_header.xml ?

Comment: What I meant is `bg_player_header.xml` isn't inside your layout folder. when you do "@layout" it will look for that particular file inside layout folder.

Comment: Yes. You need to create it.

Comment: Okay , got that. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: no problem ! :)